# XDocument says Data at the root level is invalid?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, deserialization

I'm trying to parse an XML, which is at this [url](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/djfonplaz/subscriptions?v=2):

```
try
{
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(requestedURL);
    Response.Write("asd: " + xDoc.Descendants("entry").Count());
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    Response.Write(err.Message);
}
```

but it replies with `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `XDocument.Load` not `XDocument.Parse`. That would be because `XDocument.Parse` expects to receive an XML string, while you are trying to load it from a URL.

**EDIT**

You also have problem with XML namespaces. Try this

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(requestedURL);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var count = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry").Count();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx

Comment: Already do this, but `xDoc.Descendants("entry").Count()` says 0, which are not 0. So I guess load does not parse XML?

Comment: @markzzz Ask this to xml provider. It uses this `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` as the default namespace.

Comment: I mean: why I need to use Namespace in XDocument! The field is called `entry`, not `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom entry`

Comment: @markzzz I think you got confused with the syntax. This is the same as above `var entry = XName.Get("entry", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
            var count = xDoc.Descendants(entry).Count();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
try
{
  var xDoc = XDocument.Load(requestedURL);
  Response.Write("asd: " + xDoc.Descendants("entry").Count());
}
catch (Exception err)
{
  Response.Write(err.Message);
}
```